# Using health check or ping to improve rest api performance

Tags: java, performance, rest, tomcat

We noticed that our API performance improved as we increase the health check frequency with one of the downstream. The reason for API performance is that the http connection was getting re-used with health check. The keepalive timeout for the downstream was 55s and keeping a healthcheck frequency of 30s would ensure that all API request will get a live connection to reuse. While this approach works, this does not look a strategic solution. Our downstream has moved to AWS where the keepalive timeout is 2s. Is there a solution better than ping/ health-check to ensure that our API always gets a live connection. The performance improvement is significant ~400ms per request.

Answer (score 0):

It's ok.

Possible solutions are:

- get a better connection (dedicated line) to your downstream, so that establishing the connection costs less
- increase keep-alive. It might not be safe, as you could be DDoSed just by allocating a lot of connections.
- do a ping/health-check basing on the request frequency of your upstream. It's safer than increasing keep-alive, and it seems that your upstream requests rate is quite low (about 1 request per minute or lower) so it would be the cheapest and safest option.

Generally speaking, your ping/health-check is a keep-alive sort of thing anyway.